# Create component vue from basic javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor

I would like to know how can I transpose a base javascript to vue component.

Currently, I have this :

```
<textarea id="my-editor" name="content" class="form-control">{!! old('content', 'test editor content') !!}</textarea>

<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
          var options = {
              filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
              filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token=',
              filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
              filebrowserUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&_token='
          };

          CKEDITOR.replace('my-editor', options);
</script>
```

I tried to inject the library and create a vue 3 component :

```
import CKEDITOR from '../../js/Librairies/ckeditor-4-6-2';

let myApp = createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) });
...
myApp.use(CKEDITOR, 'CKEDITOR')
```

Component :

```
<template>
    <div>
         <textarea ref="editor">TextareaCkEditor</textarea>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

export default {
    name: 'TextareaCkEditor',
    inject: ['CKEDITOR'],
    setup(props, context) {
        const editor = ref(null);

        onMounted(() => {
            CKEDITOR.replace(editor, {
                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
                filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token=',
                filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
                filebrowserUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&_token='
            });
        })

        return { editor }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

But CkEditor doesn't work, I have always an error in the console :

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `CKEDITOR.replace(editor, {` should be `CKEDITOR.replace(editor.value, {` as it's inside the setup context meaning the editor will be a proxy for the current value thus accessing editor directly will not yield an element.

Comment: @Braks If I use editor.value it's like good ! Thank you ! But the path to load the plugin is not really good, and I can't use image and link plugins.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes but I would like to use filebrowserImageBrowseUrl, filebrowserImageUploadUrl, filebrowserBrowseUrl and filebrowserUploadUrl property